# Is there a way to initialize multiple atom states before testing a component in react-testing -library?

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

Right now I am initializing a single atom state as follows

```
<RecoilRoot initializeState={(snap: any): any => snap.set( oneTimeData, onetimeParameter)}>
```

I am trying to add another atom `errors` to the above code.

```
<RecoilRoot initializeState={(snap: any): any => snap.set( (oneTimeData, onetimeParameter), (errors, errorsParameter) }>
```

Is this the correct usage?

Comment: I think this what `selectors` are made of in `recoil`. Instead of atoms try this using selectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I offer this edit:

```
<RecoilRoot initializeState={(snap: any): any => {snap.set( oneTimeData, onetimeParameter);
snap.set(errors, errorsParameter);}}>
```